# Unexplained JAXBException when Unmarshalling using Java 6

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a situation that on rare occasion, My jaxb unmarshaller throws a JAXBException with the following message:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: null
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:173) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
```

Now this happens in the middle of the night, and only on occasion (I have seen it happen 2-3 times over the course of an entire month).

However, I don't know why it is happening.  The file it is reading exists, the system is not out of memory, etc.  It even appears to correct itself within the hour.

Any insight to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have some `IOException`:

https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/69471fb27af6a9e990ef2a7873aab64a18e87640/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/UnmarshallerImpl.java#L261

But this is hard to impossible to tell what the core problem is.

Comment: It would have been nice if they would have thrown the `IOException`  instead. Not sure what the exception would be since the file exists on the drive.